# The effects of upgrading to latest version of Ubuntu from 16.04 on VirtualBox

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

What are the effects of upgrading to latest version of Ubuntu from 16.04? I am worried about my VirtualBox ver 5.1.38 and I'm wondering if there are any known major issues. Will it be damaged or erased by the upgrade?

Comment: This question isn't too broad at all. They're wondering whether their virtual machines will be damaged by the upgrade process itself or by 18.04's upgraded programs, not by their cat. While this can't be answered definitively, it can be answered reasonably.

Comment: No I'm satisfied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why it would be damaged or erased in any way from a proper upgrade as long as you're using the 64-bit version since I do see a 64-bit build for Ubuntu 18.04 for the version in question on VirtualBox's website: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_1

Although, it does seem like this is an older version of virtualbox and I would highly recommend updating it once you do upgrade, especially since on that same page I shared, it said that this version is no longer supported. Newer version: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

If you're absolutely paranoid or have anything super sensitive on there though, then I recommend cloning your drive if possible before the upgrade. All I can say is I've upgraded a few machines to the latest 18.04.1 LTS and have had no issues myself, but then again, I haven't messed with VirtualBox on Linux. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you all, I was asking to see if there was a known issue with doing this, I suspect there isn't again thank you

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted your question as you upgrading your actual computer (rather than one of your virtual machines) to use Ubuntu 18.04 and that you're worried that VirtualBox will be messed up when you're done.

The short answer is that, unless you're erasing everything and starting over, upgrading shouldn't touch your virtual machine files since they're in your home directory and the system upgrade doesn't generally touch anything in home directories.

VirtualBox itself will be upgraded with your system. Problems from doing this are rare, but they can be fixed as long as your virtual machine files are still there.

To be on the safe side, though, you can back up your virtual machines if you have an external hard drive that's large enough to hold them. Shut down all of the virtual machines and, just inside your home folder, copy the `VirtualBox VMs` folder or some of the virtual machines inside of it to the external hard drive.

You can also copy the `VirtualBox VMs` folder to somewhere else on your computer's internal hard drive. That way you'll have two backups.

You can also do backups more frequently than once per system upgrade. That way if something goes wrong, you don't lose everything. You just lose all the changes since you last backed up.

Comment: Thank you, I imagine there is no known issue with this, which is why I posted this question